# В Docker контейнер не запускается после docker start (Linux)

Tags: linux, docker

1. `$ docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
dg4   postgres "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Exited (127) 22 minutes ago       test-postgres
```

Пытаюсь запустить контейнер

2. `$ docker exec -it test-postgres /bin/bash`

```
Error response from daemon: Container[id] is not running
```

3. `$ docker start [id]`

```
id
```

4. Что показывает docker inspect

`docker inspect [id]`

```json
"State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 127,
            "Error": "",
}
```

Comment: Исправьте свой вопрос. Используя кнопку ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1549230/edit) и отформатруйте ваш вопрос (уберите команды в блоки кода). Ваш вопрос не описывает ваших действий над контейнером. Почему вы производите `exec` до старта контейнера? Вы уверены что правильно запускайте контейнер?

Comment: а что в логах? `docker logs [id]`

Comment: Там же ясно видна ошибка 127 - что-то не найдено. Проверяйте свой entrypoint и что там еще нужно для этого контейнера.